# Why does Convert.ToInt32( Console.Read() ) return 53 instead of 5?

Tags: c#

This program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x;
    Console.Write("Enter number:");
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
    Console.WriteLine($"Output: {x}");
}
```

Console text:

```
Enter number: 5
Output: 53

Press any key to continue...
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Input number 5 but Output not 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Console.Read()` reads a **single character** as a `char`, and not the whole line as a `string`.
- `char` values are actually integers themselves and are not processed as text by C#/.NET for most operations, and this can throw-off beginners.
- The integer value of `'5'` (as a `char`) [is 53 in ASCII and Unicode](http://www.asciitable.com/).
- `Convert.ToInt32(Char)` treats the `char` value as an integer (so `'5'` is `53`) and converts that to an `Int32` value instead of parsing the character as a decimal digit.

  - I strongly recommend avoiding the `Convert` class. There are much better alternatives in the .NET Framework (such as `Int32.TryParse`).

To fix this, use `Console.ReadLine()` and `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` so you can gracefully handle invalid input.

```
while( true )
{
    Console.Write( "Enter number: " );
    String input = Console.ReadLine();
    if( Int32.TryParse( input, out Int32 value ) ) // ideally use the overload with NumberStyles.Any and CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to be explicit.
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"Output: {value}" );
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Please enter a valid number." ); 
    }
}
```